# Is this curved text blend possible in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, illustrator-effects

I've started playing around in illustrator and came to a full stop when I tried to find a way to create a side curve to a text blend (cause I don't know the limitations of the blend tool)

Here's what I'm trying to create (these are a billion layers individually colored (poorly) and resized and frankly just nuts AND makes illustrator crash.

[image]

And this is just simple text blend

[image]

Can I ask, what is this text effect even called? Seen it on 70's and 80's logos/cartoons but did not know how to google more information about this. I went with the blend tool to start cause I like its gradient effect but that of course only goes in a straight line or if you change the spine curves only to one direction.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? Does it have to be done manually as in drawn or is there some other simpler way to do it?

Comment: I believe that this 'look' was inspired by early broadcast effects. Look at Dr Who in the 70's (and many Sci Fi movies) you will see that they had a simple range of filters for the titles including a vortex effect. I can remember some of these appearing in early Avid releases for desktop video. Like drop shadow they were over used because you only had a few to choose from.  I circumvented those with Macromedia Director in 1997, porting Mac based text animations to Betacam SP tape for broadcast including a sting for MTV - it gave us many more options although would take all night to render.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Each blend has a spine.

- Use the **Direct Selection Tool** to select the bottom point of the spine
  and convert it to a smooth point clicking the **Convert Selected
  Point to Smooth** icon at the top options bar
- Move up the top handler holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to do it at 90º
- Increase the blend steps

[image]

Comment: You absolutely fantastic being!!!! This is so simple I could cry ... how did I not think of playing with the spine - Thank you so much for explaining this to me!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Not related to the actual question, but what did you use to create the animated example?

Comment: @Copes This is Illustrator

Comment: @Copes ...Kap...